# Как использовать update в Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Вот такой код, видимо, учитывает только первый аргумент:

```
$command->update('vgok_site.a_analiz_data', array('timeval' => 'now()',), 
        'analiz_id=:id', array(':id' => $id_analiz), 
        'elem_id=:id', array(':id' => 49)
);
```

В то время как мне надо:

```
UPDATE vgok_site.a_analiz_data SET timeval = now()
WHERE analiz_id = 2014 AND elem_id = 49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам верно сказали что схему\базу не стоит указывать, а ваша проблема связана с  аргументами, вы передаете в функцию **шесть** параметров, хотя [функция](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#update-detail) принимает всего **четыре**.

```
update(string $table, array $columns, mixed $conditions='', array $params=array ( ))
```

и того:

```
$command->update(
    'a_analiz_data',
    array('timeval' => 'now()'), 
    'analiz_id=:analiz_id AND elem_id=:elem_id',        //mixed $conditions
    array(':analiz_id' => $id_analiz, ':elem_id' => 49)  //array $params
);
```

Comment: чую что вы правы (пока проверить не могу). откуды вы узнали такие тонкости? можно пруф?

Comment: кст можно ж было не заморачиваться и так писать: http://pastebin.com/bKzRUNgg ?

Comment: @des1roer тонкости работы с методами можно спокойно найти в документации фреймоворка))  `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#update-detail`... и подставлять напрямую значения не советую..на то они и подготовленные, чтоб было безопаснее

Comment: да меня всегда убивало что написано дурным языком и примеров ни одного. вот как первоначально было - это с офф форума скопировано